# How to make JUnit tests access remote server folder when ran thru a jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, junit

I'm running my Junit tests using a jenkins job, some of the tests require access to a remote server folder in order to create a text file on the folder. How do I configure jenkins job with a remote server for JUnit tests to create a text on the server?

I'm using a maven project which has logic to create a text file on the server. It works all good when I run JUnit tests locally in my IDE because I have access to localhost.

Thanks for reading! will greatly appreciate if someone guides me regarding this.

Comment: Consider writing the unit test so that no directory is needed for example by using mocks.

Answer (score 1):

Make that remote server as a slave node of jenkins, then execute the job that creates folder on the slave, so that it will create the text file on the remove server as you intended.